# RESTEasy proxy for interface with generic

Tags: java, resteasy

I have a question about a REST client I'm using, but first I'll explain the service:

I have an interface:

```
public interface IEntityResource<T extends BaseEntity>{
    public List<T> findAll();
}
```

I have a REST provider that does this:

```
@Path("system")
public class SystemResource extends AbstractEntityResource<PITSystem>{
     // Some stuff here
}
```

My AbstractEntityResource does this:

```
@Override
public List<T> findAll() {
    L.error("Returning all");
    for(T entity : getEntityDao().findAll()){
        L.error("Returning class: " + entity.getClass());
    }
    return getEntityDao().findAll();
}
```

All of this works great and has 100% test coverage.  When I deploy it I can add entities no problem.

My client looks like this:

```
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
interface PITSystemInterface extends IEntityResource<PITSystem>{}

public class ProxyClientExample {
    public static void main(String ar[]) throws Exception{
        ProxyClientExample pce = new ProxyClientExample();

        ResteasyClient client = new ResteasyClientBuilder().build();
        WebTarget target = client.target("http://mike:mike@localhost:8080/pit-beta1/rest/v1/system");
        ResteasyWebTarget rtarget = (ResteasyWebTarget) target;

        PITSystemInterface simple = rtarget.proxy(PITSystemInterface.class);
        PITSystem s = new PITSystem();
        s.setName("Test " + new java.util.Date().getTime());
        s.setDescription("Created: " + new java.util.Date().getTime());
        simple.create(s);
        System.err.println(simple.getStatus());
        for(PITSystem system : simple.findAll()){
            System.err.println(system);
        }
    }
}
```

Problem is the for loop at the bottom gives me an exception:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: BaseEntity cannot be cast to PITSystem`

If I change the for loop to be `BaseEntity` it works.  My server log message says:

> Returning class: class PITSystem
>
> Returning class: class PITSystem
>
> Returning class: class PITSystem

For some reason, the RESTEasy client appears to think it is the BaseEntity, but it is not.  Any ideas why?